# I can't tell if this rotation function is working as expected

Tags: c, rotation

So I derived a rotation function like this:

- I want to rotate (a, b, c) around the x axis
- the value of `a` will not change
- this is equivalent to rotating (b, c) around the origin in a 2d map
- for a 2d map in polar coordinates, rotating `d` degrees is as simple as:
  `θ = θ + d`
- for a point P(x, y), `x = Rcos(θ)` and `y = Rsin(θ)`
- so let Q be the point after rotation, then `Q = (Rcos(θ + d), Rsin(θ + d))`

since R<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> and θ = arctan(y/x):

Q = (sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) * cos(arctan(y/x) + d, sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) * sin(arctan(y/x) + d)

I then made a C function that given a coordinate: `a` and `rot_amount` (usually 1) it would rotate my coordinate for me.

```
static void     xrotate_coor(t_coor *a, int rot_amount)
{
        double d;
        double e;

        d = a->y;
        e = a->z;
        if (e == 0 && d == 0)
                return ;
        if (d == 0)
        {
                a->y = sqrt(d * d + e * e) * cos(atan(INFIN) + rot_amount * M_PI / 50);
                a->z = sqrt(d * d + e * e) * sin(atan(INFIN) + rot_amount * M_PI / 50);
                return  ;
        }
        a->y = sqrt(d * d + e * e) * cos(atan(e / d) + rot_amount * M_PI / 50);
        a->z = sqrt(d * d + e * e) * sin(atan(e / d) + rot_amount * M_PI / 50);
}
```

INFIN is a macro I set to 999999.

I am not sure if it is correct though since using this formula the shape I am rotating is getting deformed so I feel like there is a flaw in my logic somewhere...

Comment: When you say it is being deformed, is it being deformed after the first rotation, or is it progressively becoming more deformed as you continue to rotate?

Comment: once it completes a full cycle it goes back to its original position

Comment: If that answer doesn't describe what you're seeing, just say so and I'll delete it.

Comment: I don't think it is precision loss because the some of the deformations can be quite violent as opposed to a steady loss of form. But your answer is something I didn't consider so thank you

Comment: ok I am really stupid I forgot to return after the `if (d == 0)`

Comment: changed but still doesn't work :/

Comment: arctan(y/x) = arctan((-y)/(-x)), which means a rotation defined that way cannot cover the entire unit circle. What you should do, instead, is use the traditional rotation formula: let `c = cos(d)` and `s = sin(d)`, where `d` is the amount of rotation (in radians in C). Then, `x_new = c*x_old - s*y_old` and `y_new = s*x_old + c*y_old`. Note that you must not mix old (unrotated) and new (rotated) coordinates when calculating; the calculations are done on the old coordinates only. Otherwise you get taffy, stretchy results.

Comment: What is the range of `int rot_amount` used?

Comment: for this just assume its always 1

Comment: Which purpose should this server: `atan(INFIN)`? If you have constant angle, you can just use a constant (`M_PI/2`) instead of calling a function.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you could calculate the length `sqrt(d * d + e * e)` once in advance and don't call the function twice. BTW: If you mean `y` and `z`, why do you call the variables `d` and `e` instead?

Comment: @Gerhardh Note that `M_PI` is not available from a compliant std C library.  `acos(0)` is a substitute that provides a portable `π/2`.

Comment: Simplification: `sqrt(d * d + e * e)` --> `hypot(d,  e)`

Comment: @chux, the code already uses `M_PI / 50`

Comment: @Gerhardh Fair point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the shape I am rotating is getting deformed  ...

`atan(e / d)` loses the 4 quadrant nature of `a->y, a->z;`.  Consider that with OP's code, if the `y,z` are negated, the same result ensues. [@Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703833/i-cant-tell-if-this-rotation-function-is-working-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment78366873_45703833)

```
    d = -(a->y);
    e = -(a->z);
    ...
    atan(e / d)
```

Instead use a 4 quadrant arctangent.

> `double atan2(double y, double x);`
>   The `atan2` functions compute the value of the arc tangent of `y`/`x`, using the signs of both arguments to determine the quadrant of the return value. A domain error may occur if both arguments are zero.

Other suggested improvements below too.

```
#include <math.h>

static void xrotate_coor(t_coor *a, int rot_amount) {
  double d = a->y;
  double e = a->z;
  double r = hypot(d, e);  // vs. sqrt(d * d + e * e)

  if (r) {
    double angle = atan2(e, d);
    angle += rot_amount * (M_PI / 50);
    a->y = r * cos(angle);
    a->z = r * sin(angle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing the accumulation of errors in the calculations.  This is caused by the nature of how numbers are represented in computers.

The typical way to handle this problem in computer graphics is to keep the object's coordinates fixed and translate them to the position required for the frame being rendered.  In your case, this would mean that rather than progressively rotating the object, leave the object in its original position and simply calculate the translation to the current angle around the X-axis based on where it should currently be displayed.

In other words, if you are translating 360 degrees total 20 degrees at a time, display the translated coordinates at 20 degrees in the first iteration and the translated coordinates at 40 degrees in the second iteration rather than actually translating 20 degrees each time.